# Rails scope model data by user_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails application where a user longs in and I have the user_id in the session. The next step is to create a scope for all model data shown to the user where `data.user_id = session[:user_id]`.

I know I can do the following in each of my controllers

```
Controller.find_all_by_user_id(session[:user_id])
```

Yet to me it seems there is probably a better solution. I found the possibility to add a scope to the model, yet the session is not known here and MVC pattern wise it is probably not a good idea to have it there. Is there a solution to apply such a user_id restriction to all data coming from the models or should I just use the `find_all_by_user_id` for every controller function that has userdata in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to access some data by `user_id`. Which means that you can define relationship in the user model as `has_many :this_and_that` or something like that. It it is right, then you can create a `before_filter` or even better a function in your application controller in which you get your current user instance. Trough this instance, you can access all available data to that user. You can even make that function a helper function, and you can use that in a view.

```
#User.erb
has_many :other_data

#ApplicationConroller.erb
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
end

#OtherControllers
def index
  @other_datas = current_user.other_datas
end
```

Comment: This works excellent and seems like a very neat solutions. Thanks!

Comment: This is a great answer, and also this is well explained in the "Ruby on Rails Tutorial" by Michael Hartl

Answer (score 1):

You can have `before_filter :load_user_data, :if => current_user` or something like that.
Method will look like that:

```
def load_user_data  
 @data = ModelName.where(user_id: session[:user_id]) 
end
```

`@data` will be `ActiveRecord::Relation` and will be  chainable. Also using `find_all_by_user_id` in each controller not that bad, if you really need it.